# Fetch data from Header (<H></H>) using Selenium

Tags: java, html, css, selenium

I got a website, which got the following snippet of code:

```
<div class="list_item_normal">

  <div class="main_content">
    <div class="img_wrap">
      <a href="/home/Detaljer/9781118093757"><img alt="Miniaturebillede af omslaget til Operating System Concepts" src="/images/product_thumb/9781/118/093/9781118093757.jpg?1354045210" title="Miniaturebillede af omslaget til Operating System Concepts" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="data_wrap">
        <h4>
        <!-- Added by sathiyaraj regarding E-book integration CR -->

        <a href="/home/Detaljer/9781118093757">Operating System Concepts</a> <small style='background-color:yellow;'></small>
        </h4>



        <h5>

         Abraham Silberschatz and Peter B. Galvin
          (2013)
        </h5>

        <div class="imprint">




        John Wiley & Sons, Limited
        </div>

        <div class="price">

           610,00 kr.        


        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I need to get what is encased within the h5 tag only. I've tried to do this the past 30 minutes without luck. My current piece of code looks like this:

```
    content = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'content')]"));
    List<WebElement> list
            = content.findElements(
                    By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'list_item_normal')]"));
    System.out.println(list.size()); // Just for debugging purposes
    for (WebElement e : list) {
        System.out.println(e.findElement(By.xpath("//h5")).getText());
    }

    driver.close();
}
```

It's a book store and the author is within the h5 tag. Now using the code above just produce a list of 10 identical authors even though many of them have different authors. I don't know where I am going wrong with this.

So how do I fetch data which is within that specific tag?

EDIT:

Here is the entire page HTML: http://pastebin.com/QALCvtaG

Comment: I can't see the class 'list_item_normal' in your code. And is 'Syso(list.size());' printing as expected?

Comment: @VageeshBhasin I will add that, and yes it prints 10 which is the number of books shown on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think your mistake is trying to find elements within elements without implying so in xpath. Correct the line in your code to following, it should work.

```
 System.out.println(e.findElement(By.xpath(".//h5")).getText());
```

You might also have to correct xpath in following line:

```
List<WebElement> list = content.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class= 'list_item_normal']"));
```

The only thing that I have changed is that I have added a dot before each of your xpath for finding elements within element.

Comment: If I do that, the list returns 0 and thus prints nothing out.

Comment: That means the element with class 'list_item_normal' is not a child of any element with class containing 'content'. Moreover why are you using contains? Isn't there a specific class of the parent node within which all the 'list_item_normal' reside?

Comment: I am no HTML genius here. I code Java and C# and this assignment is stupid as balls for making us debug HTML in the first place :P Let me add some more HTML to the main post. Maybe you can see where I am going wrong with interpreting it.

Comment: Turns out, removing the part about getting the elements from "content" and just go straight looking for "list_item_normal" solved the issue. Your code made it work in the end so you'll get an accepted answer.

Comment: Yeah i got busy so couldn't answer. I looked into your html and found out there are 24 matching nodes for your element content. So driver saves 1st matching element in variable **content** and goes on to look inside it for further elements. So when you removed 1st line of your code, it searched whole page for 'list_item_normal' and  saved all of it in the list variable list. After this it looked only inside each 'list_item_normal' for a h5. Hence your corrected code worked like a charm. However you can improve performance by change xpath as updated in my answer.